# Can I print cell contents with cell comments at end of worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, comments

How do I print the contents of a commented cell along with the cell comments at the end of a worksheet?  I know how to print the comments at the end, but is it possible to add in the cell contents?

#### Example:

Cell E96 in my worksheet contains: *"Remove storm windows"*

The comment for cell E96: *"6 windows plus 1 small...say .5 hours each = 3.5 hours"*

#### When I print a worksheet with comments appended after the worksheet I get:

> Cell | E96
>
> Comment | 6 windows plus 1 small...say .5 hours each = 3.5 hours

#### I'd like to add the contents of the commented cell there too, like this :

*(or something similar, I'm flexible)*

> Cell | E96 *Remove storm windows*
>
> Comment | 6 windows plus 1 small...say .5 hours each = 3.5 hours

Comment: I don't believe you will able to find a way to alter how Excel prints out comments. The best you will be able to do is VBA code to create a custom list of commented cells, i.e., a cell's address, contents, and comment. Take a look at the code [here](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/08/27/print-a-customized-list-of-excel-comments/), which looks like it does pretty much all of what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the code from [chuffs link](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/08/27/print-a-customized-list-of-excel-comments/#comment-7252) and corrected some errors.

The macro extracts the cell address, cell value, author, comment text of all commented cells and writes them to a new worksheet. This sheet can be printed separately with your normal sheet.

- open your workbook and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
- insert the code below into *sheet1* or a new module
- close the VBA editor and go back to the sheet with your comments
- press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> and execute the macro

---

```
Sub ListComments()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim X As Long, RngName As String, newwks As Worksheet, curwks As Worksheet

    Set curwks = ActiveSheet
    If curwks.Comments.Count Then

        Set newwks = Worksheets.Add
        newwks.Range("A1").Resize(1, 4) = Array("Address", "Cell Value", "Author", "Comment")

        On Error Resume Next
        For X = 1 To curwks.Comments.Count
            With curwks.Comments.Item(X)
                newwks.Range("A1").Offset(X, 0).Resize(1, 4) = _
                    Array(.Parent.Address(False, False), .Parent.Value, .Author, .Text)
            End With
        Next
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this will help you but you could try **CTRL V** it is supposed to copy formulas, values etc. I don't know if this will do what you want but thought you might want to try it if you are not already aware of this function.

Comment: This doesn't help solve the question